# Understanding big O notation complexity

Tags: time, complexity-theory

Can someone please help me understand the following?  Prove that 1000n^3 = O(n^3). Use the

mathematical definition of O(f(n))!

Comment: You are in the wrong place man...

Comment: What did you try? we will not do your homework for you

Comment: math.stackexchange.com/‎

Comment: Actually it better fits cs.stackexchange.com, But not really because it is still homework dump

Answer (score 0):

This is not the rigth place...by the way I will try to explain it...

[image]

So

[image]

and `l`

[image]

[image] is limited

So `l = 1000`

[image]

So it is true